# Configure Search 'This Site' to include Lists from Parent Site

Tags: sharepoint-online, search

In the default search bar in the top-right of each site, there is an option to search 'This Site'.

We have a couple lists stored on our parent site that need to be searched on a particular child site when searching 'This Site'.

I cannot move the lists under the child site using 'Save as Template' since the lists all exceed the 500 MB size limit.

**Can I edit the Result Sources, Query Rules, or Search Settings on the child site to incorporate the parent-level lists in the 'This Site' search results?**

If so, how do I go about doing that?

I am using SharePoint Online and have access to SharePoint Designer.

Answer (score 0):

You can go to site settings in this subsite->Search->Search Settings.

Click “This Site” under Configure Search Navigation->Click “Edit”. In the Navigation Link dialog, add “&mypath='https://domain.sharepoint.com/sites/yoursite/listname' ” behind the URL, such as “ /sites/yoursite/subsite1/_layouts/15/osssearchresults.aspx?u={contexturl}&mypath='https://domain.sharepoint.com/sites/yoursite/listname”.

Save and wait for some time to check if it works.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Can I add in multiple paths? I have 5 additional URL locations I'd like it to search. I tried adding them in as `&mypath='URL'&mypath='URL'&mypath='URL'` etc.